# How to set-up a this html outline for tex4ht with toc on the left+main text+footnotes

Tags: tex4ht, html

I have discovered a nice outline to have a html page with:

- a table of content
- the main text
- the footnotes at the bottom of each page
- all of these windows can be resized with the cursor of the mouse

http://ditext.com/sellars/epm.html
[image]

I would like to know how to have a configuration file which would tell tex4ht to format my html page like this.

Answer (score -1):

The way it can be done is shown there [Trouble building a site with frames using Tex4ht](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/317686/trouble-building-a-site-with-frames-using-tex4ht).