# Trouble building a site with frames using Tex4ht

Tags: tex4ht, htlatex

via Tex4ht with frames, using the configuration file cc.cfg

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml,sections+,ext=htm,charset="utf-8",2,frames}

\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<title>Good Morning</title>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<link rel="shortcut icon"  href="css/images/favicon.ico" />\Hnewline}}


\Configure{BODY}
{%
  \HorFrames{*,3*}\Frame{s1}\Frame[ name="f2"]{s2}
  \NoFrames
  \PushStack\eBody{}
  \SubConfig

  \HPage[p1]{hello}\Link{}{s1}\EndLink
  \bgroup
  \Configure{Link}{a}{target="f2" href=}{name=}{}
  \tableofcontents
  \egroup
  \EndHPage{p1} \Tg<br />

  \HPage[p2]{text2222}\Link{}{s2}\EndLink
    }
    {  \EndHPage{p2}}
    \Configure{DOCTYPE}
    {\HCode{<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
\Hnewline  "http://Hello1">\Hnewline}}

  \def\SubConfig{%
  \Configure{BODY}
   {\PushStack\eBody{x}\Tg<body>}
   {\PopStack\eBody\temp
 \ifx \temp\empty \EndFrames \else\Tg</body>\fi}

  \Configure{DOCTYPE}
   {\HCode{%
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     \Hnewline "http://Hello2"> \Hnewline}}

   }
    \begin{document}  


    \EndPreamble
```

I am trying to compile the following tex file  site_test.tex

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\usepackage{minitoc}  

\begin{document}

\dominitoc

\title{This is a title}
\date{Today is today}
\author{Joe}

\maketitle
\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter alpha}
\section{Alpha prime}
\section{Alpha secundus}
\subsection{Hello}
\subsection{Ciao}

\chapter{Chapter beta}
\section{bye}
\section{Here you are}

\end{document}
```

via the command (on MikteX Windows 8)

```
 htlatex site_test.tex "cc.cfg"
```

and I obtain the following output[image]

I have some problems with it I would like to adress

1. The page should be called "Good Morning" via

   ```
   \Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<title>Good Morning</title>\Hnewline}}
   ```

   but it takes the title of the document "This is a title" (the icon works)
2. I am trying to put title, date and author above the table of content, so far no success.
3. In the table of content, there are 2 "contents". How to remove at least one ?
4. (Does anyone know a way to improve the site by modifying the css file ?)

I understant the global structure of the code but not enough. I can post the HTML ouputs if necessary. Does anyone has a working example ? 
Any help is welcome :)

Comment: update : in order to deal with the margin, replace the corresponding line by   `\HorFrames{*,3*}\Frame[  marginwidth="20"    name="f1"]{s1}\Frame[  marginwidth="20"    name="f2"]{s2} `

Comment: update : you can add an horizontal frame by defining `\VerFrames{*,3*}\Frame{v1}` together with defining`\Hpage[v1]....` as explained by @jagath.

Answer (score 4):

I think this might be helpful. The `\tableofcontents` used in the TeX file is now commented as this cause the duplication of the **Contents** title in the frame. The modified TeX file is given below:

```
\documentclass{book}
%\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\pdfcompresslevel=9
\usepackage{minitoc}  

\begin{document}

\dominitoc

\title{This is a title}
\date{Today is today}
\author{Joe}

\maketitle
%\tableofcontents

\chapter{Chapter alpha}
\section{Alpha prime}
\section{Alpha secundus}
\subsection{Hello}
\subsection{Ciao}

\chapter{Chapter beta}
\section{bye}
\section{Here you are}

\end{document}
```

I will now try to answer your queries:

1. The content which is provided as the argument of `\title` command will appear inside `<title>...</title>` in the HTML. If you want to get rid of the default text, there is an easy **dirty** way to do that:

   ```
    \Configure{TITLE}{\HCode{<title>}\special{t4ht@[}}{\special{t4ht@]}Good Morning\HCode{</title>\Hnewline}}
   ```

All the characters between `\special{t4ht@[}` and `\special{t4ht@]}` will be ignored and the real content of the title will now be stripped and your custom title `Good Morning` will now appear as title. Earlier in your case, the browser uses the first `<title>...</title>` element to display the title.

2. It is not easy to put the values of `\title`, `\author` and `\date` to toc at first compilation. Hence, I have redefined the standard commands so that its arguments is written to auxiliary file on first compilation as `\Title`, `\Author` and `\Date` respectively. Please note that now I have not considered handling the optional arguments if available by default.

   ```
   \let\Title\@empty
   \let\Author\@empty
   \let\Date\@empty
   \def\title#1{\gdef\@title{#1}
   \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\gdef\string\Title{#1}}}
   \def\author#1{\gdef\@author{#1}
   \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\gdef\string\Author{#1}}}
   \def\date#1{\gdef\@date{#1}
   \immediate\write\@auxout{\string\gdef\string\Date{#1}}}
   ```

These commands were now added to the toc, before `\tableofcontents` command as:

```
\HPage[p1]{hello}\Link{}{s1}\EndLink
\bgroup
\Tg<span class="likechapterToc" >
\Tg<a target="f2" href="\jobname4.html\#s2" name="">\Title\Tg</a>
\Tg</span>\Tg<br />
\Tg<span class="likechapterToc" >
\Tg<a target="f2" href="\jobname4.html\#s2" name="">\Author\Tg</a>
\Tg</span>\Tg<br />
\Tg<span class="likechapterToc" >
\Tg<a target="f2" href="\jobname4.html\#s2" name="">\Date\Tg</a>
\Tg</span>\Tg<br />
\Configure{Link}{a}{target="f2" href=}{name=}{}
\tableofcontents
\egroup
\EndHPage{p1} \Tg<br />
```

3. As we remove the `\tableofcontents` command from the TeX file, the duplicate entry from the toc frame now disappeared.
4. That might be off-topic. But someone can come up with a good suggestion.

Hence, the updated cfg is as given below:

```
\Preamble{xhtml,mathml,sections+,ext=htm,charset="utf-8",2,frames}

\Configure{TITLE}{\HCode{<title>}\special{t4ht@[}}{\special{t4ht@]}Good Morning\HCode{</title>\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11" />\Hnewline}}
\Configure{@HEAD}{\HCode{<link rel="shortcut icon"  href="css/images/favicon.ico" />\Hnewline}}

\makeatletter
\let\Title\@empty
\let\Author\@empty
\let\Date\@empty
\def\title#1{\gdef\@title{#1}
\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\gdef\string\Title{#1}}}
\def\author#1{\gdef\@author{#1}
\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\gdef\string\Author{#1}}}
\def\date#1{\gdef\@date{#1}
\immediate\write\@auxout{\string\gdef\string\Date{#1}}}
\Configure{BODY}
{\Tg<a id="title"/>%
  \HorFrames{*,3*}\Frame{s1}\Frame[ name="f2"]{s2}
  \NoFrames
  \PushStack\eBody{}
  \SubConfig

    \HPage[p1]{hello}\Link{}{s1}\EndLink
    \bgroup
    \Tg<span class="likechapterToc" >
    \Tg<a target="f2" href="\jobname4.html\#s2" name="">\Title\Tg</a>
    \Tg</span>\Tg<br />
    \Tg<span class="likechapterToc" >
    \Tg<a target="f2" href="\jobname4.html\#s2" name="">\Author\Tg</a>
    \Tg</span>\Tg<br />
    \Tg<span class="likechapterToc" >
    \Tg<a target="f2" href="\jobname4.html\#s2" name="">\Date\Tg</a>
    \Tg</span>\Tg<br />
    \Configure{Link}{a}{target="f2" href=}{name=}{}
    \tableofcontents
    \egroup
    \EndHPage{p1} \Tg<br />

  \HPage[p2]{text2222}\Link{}{s2}\EndLink
    }
    {  \EndHPage{p2}}
    \Configure{DOCTYPE}
    {\HCode{<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Frameset//EN"
\Hnewline  "http://Hello1">\Hnewline}}

  \def\SubConfig{%
  \Configure{BODY}
   {\PushStack\eBody{x}\Tg<body>}
   {\PopStack\eBody\temp
 \ifx \temp\empty \EndFrames \else\Tg</body>\fi}

  \Configure{DOCTYPE}
   {\HCode{%
     <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"     \Hnewline "http://Hello2"> \Hnewline}}

   }
\makeatother
    \begin{document}  


    \EndPreamble
```

Comment: I would not have been able to modify as such. Thanks a lot @Jagath , it works well !

Comment: @Jocelyn Happy to hear it worked.